# How to Connect to AWS EC2 Instance using PuTTY through free Wifi at cafe

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

I can connect to AWS EC2 Instance using PuTTY at my home by laptop.
But when I bring the laptop to some cafe that provides free Wifi, it ends up with timeout error.

Even though the cafe's Wifi is secured, could AWS EC2 blocks connection from cafe?

Please advise me how to connect AWS EC2 using PuTTY at a cafe or somewhere outside.

Comment: Some networks may block the ssh protocol. A VPN could work, but they might block ports for those as well.

Comment: Fix the security group attached to the EC2 instance to allow the connection from the cafe’s public IP. Make sure it includes whatever you see when you google “what’s my ip.”